# Visible grey lines over expanded widget in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile, widget

I'm completely new in Flutter and i run into a problem. Everytime I create Expanded Widget, some grey lines appear over it. Is it some kind of error?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXTYQ.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITa80.png)

My intention is to place the image at the very bottom of the screen. Is it possible to do it in other way?

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not loading/ downloading maybe url issue or something else.

Comment: The thing is that i did not try to load any image, it's just empty expanded widget

Comment: What is placeholder?

Comment: Does this widget contain some sort of image?

Comment: It's simple class privided by flutter
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Placeholder-class.html

Comment: No matter what i put inside expanded widget result is the same

Comment: removing expanded widget removes this?

Comment: Yes, but I need to place the image on very bottom of the screen and expanded widget was the only one solution so far

Comment: hi, those greylines are placeholder as I checked.